# Google Script Mail app

Tags: javascript

Could you please help me to add a CC to this script? I want to use it in our office.

```
function sendEmails() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 20;   // Number of rows to process
    // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 13, numRows, 2)
    // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
        var message = row[1];       // Second column
        var subject = "EXCEPTION REPORT";
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
        cc: "B2:B50"
    }  
}
```

Comment: It's documented quite well here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object). You jut need to add an object with a `cc` property.

Comment: Sir..What about with different  cc for example 1 column? is it possible?

Comment: different emails to cc in 1 column..

Comment: The docs I link to say `cc` is `a comma-separated list of email addresses to CC`. So you just need to turn your column into a comma-separated list.

Comment: I just tried it but its not working. Can i ask for a sample so that i can try it on my script. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a code writing service. You should post the code you've tried and show us where you are having trouble; maybe somebody will spot the problem.